# GHDL --workdir option not working when running simulation

Tags: simulation, hdl, ghdl

I am currently spending some time to get familiar with GHDL and have run into an issue I can't get around.
The folder structure I created for simulation is the following:

```
ghdl/
  +-out/
  +-run/
  +-tmp/
```

In the `run` folder is a script which calls GHDL to analyze, elaborate and run my design.
For now I'd like to put all files created by GHDL into the folder `/ghdl/out`. To do this I specify the option `--workdir=../out` whenever calling GHDL.
This is the script I have in a file inside `/ghdl/run`:

```
ghdl -i --workdir=../out ../../../rtl/test_module.vhd ../../../test/bench/test_module_tb.vhd
ghdl -m --workdir=../out -o ../out/test_module_tb test_module_tb
ghdl -r --workdir=../out test_module_tb
```

(The elaboration phase works fine, therefor I do not include any details about the RTL and testbench files).
When running the simulation script I get the following error message:

```
ghdl -r --workdir=../out test_module_tb
ghdl: file 'test_module_tb' does not exists
ghdl: Please elaborate your design.
```

I have checked, the executable `test_module_tb` is actually present in the folder `/ghdl/out`.
Am I using the `--workdir` option incorrectly? What is the right way to use GHDL in case the simulation executable is in a different directory?

PS: I am using GHDL 0.34dev (20151126) from the Fedora 23 RPM repo.

Comment: You have to run the executable created by GHDL during the elaboration step.

Comment: I am aware of that, and would expect that `ghdl -r --workdir=../out test_module_tb` will do just that. But the run command does seem to ignore the `--workdir` option and look for the executable only in the current path.

Comment: Why do you not run the executable directly via `../out/test_module_tb`? (You may consider posting a bug report on the GHDL project website instead.)

Comment: That's what I will be doing. After rereading the documentation of the run command just now I found the one sentence that makes the difference "Options are ignored". Which is a little silly since two sentences before it says "The options and arguments are the same as for the elaboration command". :-/ So this behavior seems to be by design. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Which backend are you using? `llvm` or `gcc`?

Comment: @Paebbels: It's the gcc backend. Out of interest I also got myself the latest sources from github and did build GHDL locally. Still the same. However, I still used gcc as backend. May try it again using LLVM later.

Comment: Building GHDL with llvm is much easier and the performance is a bit better than the gcc backend. I'm using `-r` only on my Windows machine, because the mcode backend does not produce an executable, so `-r` is the only option.

Comment: I couldn't find any issue report of your problem on GHDL's issue list. I reported it as [issue #65](https://github.com/tgingold/ghdl/issues/65).